# MYSQL auto_increment insert statement from two foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, tomcat

.
I'm making a database for my final year project at my University and i'm currently stuck.
I have three tables :`product`, `customer` and `product_order`.

`product` has an auto_incremented primary key `product_ID`
and `customer` also has an auto_incremented primary key `customer_ID`.

`product_order` table is where my problem lies(  iknow that mysql doesn't support @insert and @scope_identity, also @last_insert_id doesn't work for me )

I have two foreign keys both from product and customer table inside here (which are  auto_increment  ids and using the variable I saw online

`SELECT @last :=  LAST_INSERT_ID();`

only returns the last id from the product_ID and customer_ID.

I have these insert statements:

```
insert into Product values(1000 ,'Logitech Webcam C270 HD mic USB', 260, 5, 'Accessory');

insert into customer VALUES(2000, 'Rachel ' , 'Mc Roy' , 'Rach@gmail.com', 'female','1985/06/05','wlovely8', '41, Cantubury Lane, San Franscique', 2938493);

insert into product_order values(@last_id_in_Customer,  @last_id_in_Product,  'Logitech Webcam C270 HD mic USB',   260, 1);
```

- i am inserting the id's to set the range of where i want the id's to fall into; hence the reason why i put 2000 and 1000; in the other inserts I utilized null to insert the data into the table automatically

  `select * from product_order;`

  `2001    2001    Logitech Webcam C270 HD mic USB 260 1`

My output from the query i only get to insert once because the @last variable only returns once.

So my question : is there a better way of doing this?

Btw this is for a customer login webpage, so the customer wouldn't have to enter a unique primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,there is a better way of doing this Assuming that when customer is registered he will get customer_id auto-incremented ,when customer log in to system store that in session variable  and whenever he selects any product ,retrieve the customer_id from session and product_id from product table and add it in order_product table

Comment: oh ok, i see, so i'll have to create a session procedure to store all of the customer id's........can you give an example on how to do this btw ?

Comment: you know, i was thinking about doing this same thing....but i not too sure on how to go about it......hmmm

Comment: yes ,here it is assuming ur using PHP
 $_SESSION["CurrentUser"]=$username;
I have added username in above line of code u can add userid 
and later u can use it as it is  $_SESSION["CurrentUser"]
If u r with the answer mark it